# in AWS, how to configure web server security group to only accept traffic from the load balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

how to configure web server SG to only accept traffic from the load balancer in AWS?

currently, my EC2 instance's security group has an inbound rule added like this:

```
Type Protocol  Port Range  Source      
HTTP TCP       80          Anywhere    0.0.0.0/0
```

This works fine, though I am not sure if all my requests are intercepted by the load balancer (Elastic beanstalk). If I change the Source in inbound rules to point to the load balancer security group, it stops working.

What is the correct way to configure this so that web servers take requests only from the load balancer ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the load balancer in security group a (say sg-a).
Put the instance in the same security group (or a different one) and allow traffic from sg-a on port 80.

Load balancers talk to the instance on its internal address which allows you to allow traffic from one security group to another.

Comment: yes, I figured that out. The problem actually, was with DNS configuration. The best solution when using GoDaddy is to switch to using Route 53.